# I want to reverse a word in lines using unix shell scripting without using echo function

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
Teju|First|Sangamithra
```

to

```
Sangamithra|First|Teju
```

Comment: SO is NOT a coding service at all, Please post your efforts which you have put in order to solve you OWN problem and let us know then.

Comment: It is a part of problem which i am not able to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -aF'\|' -lne 'print join "|", reverse @F' < input
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each one;
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to [print](http://p3rl.org/print);
- `-a` splits the input into the `@F` array;
- `-F` specifies how to split the input (on `|` in this case);
- [join](http://p3rl.org/join) joins a list into a string;
- [reverse](http://p3rl.org/reverse) does the actual work.

Comment: can i replace input with $result some variable which contain same instead of file name??

Comment: In bash, you can use a "Here String": `perl -aF'\|' -lne 'print join "|", reverse @F' <<< "$result"`